# What is the advantage of product quantization?

Tags: algorithms, searching, nearest-neighbour

I'm reading [Product Quantization for Nearest Neighbor Search](http://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/5432202/). Quoting page 4:

> The strength of a product quantizer is to produce a large set of
>   centroids from several small sets of centroids: those associated with
>   the subquantizers

Can someone please try to explain why this happens?

My interpretation so far is that (using the paper's annotation) if each sub-vector has dimension $m$ (where $m$ is a multiple of $D$, i.e. the original vector dimension), with $k^*$ centroids for each sub-quantizer, we have that the total number of possible centroids $k$ is:

$$k = (k^*) ^ m$$

So we can obtain an huge number of centroids from a small set of $m  k^*$ centroids.

Is that correct? Please help me understanding this concept :)

Comment: We expect references to fulfill the minimal scholarly requirements and be as robust over time as possible. Please take some time to improve your post in this regard. We have collected some advice [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/a/1201/).

Comment: Note that you can use LaTeX here to typeset mathematics in a more readable way. See [here](http://meta.cs.stackexchange.com/q/271/) for a short introduction.